# Used to "grep", lost in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Suppose I want to test if there is a drive named 'Z'. First step is this;

```
Get-PSProvider |  Select-Object -Property Drives
```

This give me;

```
Drives:

...
{C, A, D, Z}
...
```

But how do I proceed to retrieve the drives and test for 'Z' ?
I have tried a lot of no-working variants....

BR/ Christer

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Test-Path cmdlet:

```
Test-Path Z:
```

Or the Get-PSDrive cmdlet:

```
Get-PSDrive Z -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Where-Object to select just the info you need:

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object { ($_.Provider -match "FileSystem") -and ($_.Name -eq "Z") }
```

Comment: No need for `Where-Object` here, because `Get-PSDrive` knows the parameter `-Name` and `-PSProvider`

Comment: Good spot - I didn't know that!